# How does the behavior of a function change if it is within a subshell?

Tags: bash, function, shell, subshell

When making functions within a script it bash, it appears that people often have the function run within a subshell, ie

```
function(){(

)}
```

instead of

```
function(){

}
```

What are the benefit/downsides of using `{()}` rather than just `{}` if any?

Comment: Aside: you can use `function() (...)` directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses cause the function to run in a subshell, which is a child process isolated from the parent shell. They're useful when you want to make process-wide environmental changes without affecting the behavior of code outside of the function.

Examples include:

- **Changing the current directory** with `cd` does not affect the parent shell. Running `cd` in a subshell is a cleaner alternative to `pushd` and `popd`.
- **Variable assignments** are isolated to the subshell. You can temporarily change global settings like `$PATH` and `$IFS` without having to carefully save and restore their values before and after.
- **Shell options** changed with `set` or `shopt` will be automatically restored when the subshell exits. I commonly write `(set -x; some-commands)` to temporarily enable command logging, for example.
- **Signal handlers** installed with `trap` are only in effect in the subshell. You can install a custom `INT` (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>) handler for the duration of a function, or a custom `EXIT` handler to run cleanup code when the function returns.

  ```
  func() {(
      echo 'entering func' >&2
      trap 'echo exiting func >&2' EXIT

      ...
  )}
  ```
- **If `exit` is called** it won't cause the entire script to exit. This is useful if you want to call `exit` from several functions down the call stack as a sort of poor man's "exception".

  Or if you want to source a script that might exit, wrapping it in a subshell will keep it from killing your script.

  ```
  (
      . ./script-that-might-exit
      echo "script set \$foo to $foo"
      echo "script changed dir to $PWD"
  )
  ```

---

Fun fact: Functions don't have to be delimited by curly braces. It's legal to omit the braces and use parentheses as the delimiters:

```
func() (
    # runs in a subshell
)
```

Comment: @jhnc True. I extended the example to something that couldn't be done just `x`.

Comment: Even more generally, the body of a function just has to be a compound command. That means not just `{...}` and `(...)`, but `for` loops, `while` loops, `if` statements, etc.

Comment: Setting *any* variable in the shell is potentially changing a global variable, unless the shell offers the `local` keyword - which modern shells do, but older shells don't, so you might see code which does it as a portability habit - because when you just do `foo=bar` in a function without a `local foo` in that function, you might be overwriting a variable named `foo` in the whole shell script, or even an environment variable named `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

If `exit` is called in a `(..)` subshell, it will only terminate that expression. Moreover, the code is free to change the values of variables as well as global options (via `set`); those changes are not seen in the surrounding code and are gone when the expression exits, which can simplify reasoning about the correctness of the code.

When you use `(...)` inside a function, watch out of this pitfall: a `return` command inside the `(...)` won't return from the function; it will just terminate the `(...)`, just like `exit`. If you have commands after the `(...)`, they will then execute.